# Can I change the font of a specific digit in a cell with a "General" format

Tags: excel, vba, fonts

I have cells with numbers only. They are not formatted as numbers or as text. I found out that the `Characters` property works only on text strings. Is there a possibility to change the colors of specific digits? (without changing the cells number format to text).

Comment: Do you want to change it when a button is pressed or when worksheet open/change event is triggered? What have you got do far?

Comment: What would the criterion for setting the color? Please give examples, and if you know what will be your general criterion, please also state it.

Comment: I jsut want to change the color of the the 1 in the 1467 which in cell A1. When I attempt to use the characters property , it changes the color of the whole number.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without converting to text because any formatting is overridden by the cells 'style' where a number is concerned. Why do you want to colour a specific number differently?

Comment: No. The characters property will only act on text strings to differentially format individual characters.

Comment: Thanks. I am just building my own Soduko solver. I want to color specific numbers on request . (I have all the possible numbers in the cell...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that. According to [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213721%28v=office.11%29.aspx), **"you cannot use the Characters method to format a portion of the text if the object doesn't support rich text"**.

A workaround for you objective is by using helper cells:

1. Write code for copying the number, and pasting it as a string in a different (helper) cell.
2. Format single digits in the helper cell.
3. Place your code under a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` event Sub, in your Worksheet module.